# PyTelegramBotAPI | regexp

Tags: python-3.x

PyTelegramBotAPI
Вопрос такой:
хотелось бы сделать, чтобы через `regexp` брало несколько элементов как в `commands=['start','help']`. Если мы там пишем через `regexp=['начало','начать']` - выбивает ошибку.

т.е через `commads` и `[]` можно взять много объектов, а через `regexp [] {} ()` выбивает ошибку. Что делать?

Как оформить?

Comment: Привиде пример исходных данных и того, что вы хотите получить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В самом регулярном выражении можно несколько вариантов перечислить через символ логический |(**или**). Например:

@bot.message_handler(regexp = 'прив(ет)?|здоров|зравствуй|приветствую|ку').

Это пример хэндлера что обрабатывает возможные приветствия. Все работать должно нормально.